# Swift - Getting Prime Factors

Tags: swift

I'm trying to do a function to return all prime factors but I think there's an error in my logic. Here's the function:

```
func getPrimeFactors(numToCheck:Int) -> Int {

        if numToCheck == 1 { return numToCheck}

        var primeFactors:Array<Int> = []
        var n = numToCheck
        var divisor = 2

        while n > divisor && n%divisor == 0 {
            primeFactors.append(divisor)
            n = n/2
        }


        for i in stride(from: 3, to: sqrt(Double(n)), by:2) {
            while n > Int(i) && n%Int(i) == 0 {
                primeFactors.append(Int(i))
                n = n/3
            }
        }

        if n > 1 {
            primeFactors.append(n)
        }

        print(primeFactors)


        return 0
    }
```

Ignore the return, I'm going to use it later once this is working. If I plug 1000 as the number to check my array ends up [2, 2, 2, 5, 41]. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You need to print/debug some values, there are various loops, which one seems to cause an issue. Is the issue linked to maths? Did you tack the algorithm or created yourself?

Comment: `n = n/3` should be `n = n/Int(i)` . You also probably want to return an *array* instead of a number. – This might be helpful: [Prime Factorisation in Swift](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/166324/prime-factorisation-in-swift) on Code Review.

Comment: The return will eventually be the highest prime. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Here is an alternative solution. https://pastebin.com/UFpExVGD